# Modifying game files hard drive

Tags: filesystems, gaming

I have a PC with the game War Thunder. The game files are in `C:\` of my computer: is it possible to move this folder to another hard drive?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: depends on the software itself. many games are completely self-contained, but others are not nearly so flexible.

Comment: Instead of moving it, reinstall it on the other hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to move this folder to another hard drive?

Yes, this is possible. Though I expect your question is "Can I move it in such a way that it will keep working" :)

For that you have at least two generic options:

1. (cleanest way). Deinstall the game. Reinstall it and specify another installation path (e.g. to D:\games\WarThunder).
2. Move the folder to D: (not copy, move, preserving rights) and create a symbolic link. This way the software still tries to access the files on the C: volme but it will get redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Like what frank Thomas and Root have said generally game aren't that easy to move, Especially war thunder as that's a primary online game which is always contact a server. I know its a ridiculous sized file to reinstall but its probably safer to reinstall it.

Check the settings of the launcher as well it may have a change directory function which should move the game files across to another location.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have War Thunder Installed on Steam but if you do use this nice little app that I have come across in my years of gaming. It is used to move games (Steam Games) from one drive to another with ease.

http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover

And if you do not have the game installed on Steam it should be safe to move the folder, from my understanding and past experience moving games (the main root folder) to another drive and launching him has no impact or changes to the game.

Ex. Moving League of Legends, GTAV, FFXIV, Master of Orion, and my other games.

(Did a game migration from an HDD to an SSD)